# Unable To Create Pdfs using Aspose in Ubuntu Docker Container

Tags: ubuntu, pdf, dockerfile, containers, aspose

I'm trying to create pdf using aspose API in docker container. When i tried creating normally, i'm able to create. But using docker container, I'm not able to create it. I have searched official Aspose documentation and found, to do this we need to install a msttcorefonts package in ubuntu. But when i tried to install this package, getting error like the below. Please help me on this.

sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer

“Package ttf-mscorefonts-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'ttf-mscorefonts-installer' has no installation candidate”

I have tried installing msttcorefonts package in ubuntu container, but i'm not able to do that.

Comment: We request you please create a topic in our official support forum (https://forum.aspose.com/c/pdf) as this discussion can appropriately be carried out. Official Aspose support forum is the right place to discuss such scenarios. This is Asad Ali and I work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.

Answer (score 0):

I just met the same issue. I have fixed using the following commands in the Dockerfile (I'm supposing this is a Debian-based image):

```
RUN apt-get install -y cabextract xfonts-utils \
  && wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/contrib/m/msttcorefonts/ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.7_all.deb \
  && dpkg -i ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.7_all.deb \
  && fc-cache -f -v
```